# Laravel 7 - Pagination on Collection

Tags: laravel

I need to get my data with pagination when I use collection.

Couldn't find any way, and nothing works that written on documents.

Here's my controller;

```
...
$data = $process->paginate(30);

$data = OrderResource::collection($data);
```

And here's my resource:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Resources;
use Carbon\Carbon;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;

use Illuminate\Http\Resources\Json\JsonResource;

class OrderResource extends JsonResource
{
    /**
     * Transform the resource into an array.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @return array
     */
    public function toArray($request)
    {
        $user = Auth::user();
        return [
            "id" => $this->id,
            "customer" => $this->customer,
            "vehicle" => $this->vehicle,
            "basket" => $this->basket,
            "total" => money_formatter($this->total),
            "discount" => $this->discount,
            "net_total" => money_formatter($this->net_total),
            "status" => $this->status,
            "payment_type" => $this->payment_type,
            "main_name" => $this->vehicle->fleet_id ? $this->vehicle->fleet->title : ($this->customer->company_id ? $this->customer->company->title : $this->customer->fullname),
            "sub_name" => $this->vehicle->fleet_id ? ($this->customer->company_id ? $this->customer->company->title : $this->customer->fullname) : '',
            "created_at" => Carbon::parse($this->created_at)->formatLocalized('%a, %d %B %Y'),
        ];
    }
}
```

Comment: what is the problem?

Comment: I tried it locally with one of my own models and it worked.What is the `$process` variable exactly? Also, remember that you won't notice any changes unless `$data` is returned as json (try `dd(json_encode($data, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT))` to see if it's the result you want.

Comment: Shouldn't this work? What's the output you're getting now? You may need to actually return it as a response to see it.

Answer (score 0):

You can add a macro inside your `AppServiceProvider.php` for this, inside the `boot` method.

```php
       /**
         * Paginate a standard Laravel Collection.
         *
         * @param int $perPage
         * @param int $total
         * @param int $page
         * @param string $pageName
         * @return array
         */
        Collection::macro('paginate', function ($perPage = 15, $total = null, $page = null, $pageName = 'page') {
            $page = $page ?: LengthAwarePaginator::resolveCurrentPage($pageName);

            return new LengthAwarePaginator(
                $this->forPage($page, $perPage),
                $total ?: $this->count(),
                $perPage,
                $page,
                [
                    'path' => LengthAwarePaginator::resolveCurrentPath(),
                    'pageName' => $pageName,
                ]
            );
        });
```

And then you can use it like this (assuming `$data` is a regular laravel collection)

```php
$data = $data->paginate(50);
dd($data);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't add any metadata (pagination links) with the `collection` method. First create a ResourceCollection with `php artisan make:resource -c OrderCollection`.

Then, in that newly created file, you can do the following.

```php
class OrderCollection extends ResourceCollection
{
    /**
     * Transform the resource collection into an array.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @return array
     */
    public function toArray($request)
    {
        $collection = [            
            'data' => OrderResource::collection($this->collection)
        ];

        if ($this->resource instanceof \Illuminate\Pagination\LengthAwarePaginator) {
            $collection['pagination'] = [
                'current_page' => $this->resource->currentPage(),
                'last_page' => $this->resource->lastPage(),
                'first_page_url' => $this->resource->url(1),
                'last_page_url' => $this->resource->url($this->resource->lastPage()),
                'prev_page_url' => $this->resource->previousPageUrl(),
                'next_page_url' => $this->resource->nextPageUrl(),
                'from' => $this->resource->firstItem(),
                'to' => $this->resource->lastItem(),
                'total' => $this->resource->total(),
                'per_page' => $this->resource->perPage(),
                'path' => $this->resource->path(),
            ];
        }

        return $collection;
    }
}
```

```php
dd(json_encode(new OrderCollection(Order::paginate(3)), JSON_PRETTY_PRINT));
```